# File not found after calling receive on form file element and file transfer adapter

Tags: forms, zend-framework

As the title says, I tried calling the receive() function either of Form Element and the Adapter Object(not one after another of course). I printed the returned value - was 1 in both cases - which means receive() returned true.
The file was not found on the server though. I tried setting encrypt type of zend form to multipart/form-data - didn't help.
I'm totally clueless so any info is welcomed.
Calling receive() on transfer adapter: file location and upload name are constants.

```
$this->uploadName = $uploadName;
$this->upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$this->upload->setDestination($this->fileLocation);
...
$val = $this->upload->receive();
$quoteName = $this->upload->getFileName($this->uploadName);
$size = $this->upload->getFileSize($this->uploadName);

calling receive on form element:
//form creation - my form extends zend form
$staticForm = Srm_Form::getForm(my form,null,null,
my config);
$staticForm->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');
$staticForm->getElement(my file element name)->setDestination(my dest);

//calling receive
$form = Srm_Form::getForm(my form,null,null,my config);
$form->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');
if(!$form->isValid($_POST)){
print_r($form->getMessages());
}
//  echo $form->getElement(my file element)->getValue();
$val = $form->getElement(my file element)->receive();
echo "bbbbbb".$val;
```

I should add that **this code works when it is called after the file element is added to the form manually** and not through use of a config file.

Okay, the problem was found - 
The destination was not set for the file element (it was set manually for the transfer adapter in other place)when handling the submitted form.

Comment: What is $this->fileLocation equal to?

Comment: path to the directory where I want the file to be placed.
The application has sufficient writing permissions and in general can and does place files there in other places in code.

Answer (score 2):

I define a simple form with the Zend_Form_Element_File element

```
<?php
class Form_UploadForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function __construct($options = null) 
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setMethod('post');
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $decors = array(
            array('ViewHelper'),
            array('HtmlTag'),//array('tag'=>'table')),
            array('Label', array('separator' => ' ')),                       // those unpredictable newlines
            array('Errors', array('separator' => ' ')),                      // in the render output
        );

        $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
        $file->setDestination('/a/b/c/upload');
        $file->setLabel('Document File Path')
              ->setRequired(true)
              ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
         $this->addElement($file);

        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Upload File');
        $this->addElement($submit);
    }
}
?>
```

My action method in the Controller is

```
function uploadAction()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = "Zend_Form File Upload Example";
    $this->view->bodyCopy = "<p>Please fill out this form.</p>";

    $form = new Form_UploadForm();

    if ($this->_request->isPost()) 
    {
        $formData = $this->_request->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) 
        {
            try 
            {
                $form->file->receive(); 
            } 
            catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) 
            {
                throw new Exception('unable to recieve : '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            $uploadedData = $form->getValues();
            //Zend_Debug::dump($form->file->getFileName(), 'tmp_file');
            $this->processFile($form->file->getFileName());
        }
        else 
        {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Note - i don't call the Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http directly

The final piece is the view

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

Comment: As I stated, it works when file element is added this way. It doesn't when it is configured in config file from which the form is created.